# Google Sheets JS Event

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I created a countdown timer in google sheets based off a set date and time.

I know how to change the date with javascript events but how would I create a trigger for the event when the time reaches 0?

Thanks in advance.

My code: 
'
function dateChange(A1) {

var d = new Date("4/10/2020 00:00:00");
  d.setDate(15);

}

'

Comment: Hi ! Could you please share  a sample of your sheet AND/OR your script to clarify your question *(make sure it does not include any sensitive information)* ? Also, do you have any installed triggers? Have you checked [the documentation for installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)? Thanks!

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the response. I am using the install-able calendar trigger already but it is either not working or my script isn't working. I will attach the script in the above post, and I just want to change the date in one cell as well. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

> Based on my understanding of your question, you are basically trying to trigger something in your sheet after you reach a certain date. Please correct me if I understood wrongly.

To achieve this, you will need to use a time driven trigger for your script function.

1. Go to your script and create a function with what you want to run when the countdown is 0 (i.e when you reach that specific date). In this example I am setting the `C1` cell to the value `TIME'S UP`.

```js
function test() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('C1').setValue('TIMES IS UP');
}
```

2. In your script window, head over to **Edit-> Current's project triggers** and add the following trigger as shown in the following picture (but of course changing the date limit of your countdown, in your case the `04/10/2020 00:00`.

[image]

3. Done ! Now this will trigger once the countdown reaches that date.

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)